# How to find the area of a segment?

Tags: circles

A portion of a circle is cut off by a straight line not passing through the centre, creating two segments. How to find the area of the smaller segment?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Is it the shape of a slice of pie minus a triangle?

Comment: It can have any area from $0$ to $\pi R^2/2$ where $R $ is the radius of the circle.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have you tried looking up “area of circular segment” on the Internet? I get pages and pages of explanations and formulas.